# What is the proper use of checkout tag (version control or payment?)

Tags: discussion, tags

Just want to seek clarification on how [checkout](/questions/tagged/checkout) should be used. As the way it is now, some are using it for payment while others are using it in a version control context. If there are more appropriate tags that should be used for either scenarios, feel free to suggest those as well.

Comment: Wow, that *is* an incredibly ambiguous tag. Not sure what to split it into, if at all. (Over 400 questions tagged!)

Comment: probably one more tag should be created to cater for the two scenarios, at least

Answer (score 7):

Well, at the risk of sounding obvious, you *could* just leave it the way it is.

It's highly likely that questions having to do with version control will also have a tag that ties it to version control, like [git](/questions/tagged/git) or [svn](/questions/tagged/svn).  You can find all of the [git](/questions/tagged/git) [checkout](/questions/tagged/checkout) questions using [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkout+git), for example.

Similarly, those questions that have to do with web development will have tags like [magento](/questions/tagged/magento), [google](/questions/tagged/google) and [paypal](/questions/tagged/paypal)  In fact, [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkout+-git+-svn+-cvs+-tfs+-version-control+-mercurial), which excludes all of the major source control systems, will get most of those.

I don't think we need to change the tag at all.  The concept is already so specific that separating them into different types of "checkout" will just make them too localized. and you'll have to ban [checkout](/questions/tagged/checkout) to keep people from using it (it's a naturally-occurring tag).

Comment: Is there a precedent for this? For now, I would still regard it as a workaround until there exist proper split candidates. Also (and fairly obvious as well), retagging is better done when there are only 400 entries

Comment: Only common sense.  The tagging system has never required every tag to be absolutely unambiguous.

Comment: There are *countless* examples of this if you look around, @prusswan. Consider [tag:templates] - this has a very specific meaning paired with C++, and a rather different meaning with, say, Django. Sure, it works *better* when there's a clear underlying commonality, as is the case with tags like [tag:regex] - but even then, you gotta accept that another tag is probably necessary in order for you to know *exactly* what it's referring to.